# Unreachable code after an inherited function call in Solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, compiler-warnings, evm

Compiling the code

```
contract Bar {

    function blockingFunction() public pure returns (bool) {
        assembly {
            return(0,0x20)
        }
    }
}

contract Foo is Bar {

    function foo() public pure returns(bool) {
        bool result = blockingFunction();
        require(result == true, "msg");
        return result;
    }
}
```

gives me a warning

```
Warning: Unreachable code.
  --> contracts/implementation/Foo.sol:18:9:
   |
18 |         require(result == true, "msg");
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


Warning: Unreachable code.
  --> contracts/implementation/Foo.sol:19:9:
   |
19 |         return result;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

which makes no sense to me. The `blockingFunction` call seems to block the following code execution, even though it should return a boolean. Can someone tell me how to fix this? This is my `hardhat.config.ts`

```js
import "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox";
import { HardhatUserConfig } from "hardhat/config";

const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  solidity: "0.8.9",
  mocha: {
    timeout: 100000000
  }
}

export default config;
```

Comment: `uint256 i = 0; if (i == 0) return result;` So `if (i == 0)` will always be `true` and everything that comes after these two lines of code can never be reached

Comment: I know, I've written it in a stupid way, though this is not the issue, the code is unreachable at `uint256 i = 0`. You can test it.

Answer (score 0):

[from docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.2/assembly.html#opcodes)

```
return(p, s)    end execution, return data mem[p…(p+s))
```

execution will end in `assembly{return(0,0x20)}` code. so when you called this

```
bool result = blockingFunction();
```

the code after this will not be executed

Comment: Do you know if there's any way of making this not block the execution?

Comment: @kuco23 why dont you use mload(0X20)

Comment: you mean I'd have to remove the `return(0, 0x20)` and write `foo()` in assembly and use `mload(0x20)` to get the boolean after calling `blockingFunction`?

Comment: mload will return `bytes memory`