# Bypassing Solidity's assembly return blocking further function execution

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, evm

Say I have

```
contract Bar {

    function blockingFunction() public pure returns (bool) {
        assembly {
            return(0,0x20)
        }
    }
}

contract Foo is Bar {

    function foo() public pure returns(bool) {
        bool result = blockingFunction();
        require(result == true, "msg");
        return result;
    }
}
```

Note that `blockingFunction` is a snip from a [larger function](https://github.com/kuco23/decentralized-anonymous-voting/blob/main/contracts/implementation/PlonkVerifier.sol#L110) that does something useful and actually returns a boolean.

The call `blockingFunction()` inside `foo` makes the following code unreachable, as `return` inside assembly blocks further execution. I first noticed this when hardhat complained as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74554194/unreachable-code-after-an-inherited-function-call-in-solidity). From the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.2/assembly.html#opcodes) it says

```
return(p, s)   end execution, return data mem[p…(p+s))
```

My way of bypassing this was to call the function as `this.blockingFunction()` (or not inherit `Bar` but pass it inside `Foo` constructor and call `blockingFunction` externally via `Bar` from `foo`) which worked inside hardhat tests, but now when testing this on a testnet, I get the same problem. How do I bypass this and actually use the return value inside a contract?

There were a couple of answers saying `require` fails after the `blockingFunction` call. I would have noticed this either in hardhat test or with testnet.

Comment: I am not sure that opcode returns a bool.  That said if you want to get a value from a contract it needs to be from a deployed contract (contract instance).  From your question it isn't clear to me what the desired outcome is.

Comment: `Bar` is a snip from a larger contract that returns a bool using `return(0, 0x20)`. The thing is I can deploy Bar as a separate contract and call `blockingFunction` from `Foo` but it is still blocking the code below. I just want to be able to use the return value from `blockingFunction` inside the `foo` function. Whatever I do, the whole execution always stops at `return(0,0x20)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` opcode returns from entire contract execution not only function execution. Instead just return from the assembly like this

```
contract Bar {
    function blockingFunction() public pure returns (bool val) {
        assembly {
            let freePointer := mload(0x40)
            // store true
            mstore(freePointer,true)
            // return the stored value without return opcode
            val:=mload(freePointer)
        }      
    }  
}

contract Foo is Bar {
    function foo() public pure returns(bool) {
        bool result = blockingFunction();
        require(result == true, "msg");
        return result;
    }
}
```

proof of work:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

```
assembly {
    return(0,0x20)
}
```

This snippet returns the value from the memory slot 0, length of the returned value is 32 bytes (hex 0x20 == dec 32).

While the [Yul docs page](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/yul.html#evm-dialect) says "end execution", it can be represented as "end execution of this particular function - not of the whole transaction". In other words, the `return` statement in your `blockingFunction()` itself does not make the rest of `foo()` unreachable.

The [Layout in Memory](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/internals/layout_in_memory.html) docs page mentions the slot 0 as "scratch space for hashing methods" and generally recommends using the memory starting at slot 4 (where the **Free memory pointer** initially points to) instead of slot 0, as the slot 0 might contain some unexpected values.

Your code does not assign any value to memory slot 0, so all it reads is really just the value from the scratch space.

I'm guessing that your local emulator returned non-zero value from the memory slot 0, which assigned the value of `bool result` to `true`, and effectively passed the `require()` condition in your `foo()` function. And that the testnet returned 0 value, which caused `bool result` to be `false` and fail the `require()` condition.

Comment: I should have mentioned that in actuallity assembly's `return(0,0x20)` is a part of a larger function that actually makes sense and assigns data to memory slot. Without using `this` in front of the `blockingFunction()` call, even hardhat says the code after is not reachable. And during hardhat testing `require` failure would generate an error where the reason (i.e. `msg`) would be visible.